# left join lateral

Tags: sql, oracle

Very simple question. Trying to use a LEFT JOIN LATERAL function in Oracle SQL Developer version 4.1.5.

Can you guys confirm if this exists (I assume so since it gives no indication that the function isn't available) and if so, what is the syntax required?

I have tried a host of different options (limit 1, offset 0 rows fetch next 1 row only, fetch 1 row only...but to no avail)

Can you please review the code below to see if anything stands out what I am missing? I simply want to create date bands on this data output.

```
SELECT    a.pol_sys_id, 
          a.pol_end_dt, 
          b.pol_end_dt AS pol_end_dt2 
FROM      staging.stgt_policy a 
LEFT JOIN lateral 
          ( 
                   select   * 
                   from     staging.stgt_policy b1 
                   WHERE    a.pol_sys_id = b1.pol_sys_id 
                   AND      b1.pol_end_dt > a.pol_end_dt 
                   ORDER BY b1.pol_end_dt
                   FETCH first 1 rows only 
                         --tried limit 1 
                         --tried offset 0 rows fetch next 1 row only 
          ) b 
ON        a.pol_sys_id = b.pol_sys_id 
ORDER BY  a.pol_sys_id. a.pol_end_dt;
```

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: for code review you can post here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: More important than your SQL Developer version is the Oracle version you are using. `LATERAL` (and `OUTER APPLY` for that matter) are only available as of Oracle 12c. Is your query running? What does it mean that you tried it (with different options) but to no avail?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9530805900346903033

Comment: Thanks Thorsten - this may explain it. Currently using Oracle 11.2.0.3. "To no avail" means the code continued to fail on each run with the "missing keyword" error which I assumed meant the functions were still available but there was a problem with the code... Seems not to be the case...